# Can I use Space + LMB to pan?

Tags: customization

Is it possible to set the space bar so when it's held down, you can pan by using LMB plus dragging? This is how panning works in a bunch of other programs.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible.

Open up the *File > User Preferences* (see 2nd image) by pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> and go the the **Input** section (the third rider on the top menu of the User Preferences window).

First, we have to remove/change the existing bindings for a <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> as well as <kbd>Space</kbd>.

1. The functionality bound to <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> click is called **Set 3D Cursor**. Search for *3D Cursor* in the search window. Remove the item by pressing the X - button.
   [image]
2. Find the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> command by searching for Space via key-binding. Remove this item as well.
   [image: Key-Binding]
3. Now search for *Rotate View*. Click on the items shortcut, then perform a left click again to enter a **Left Mouse** value. To set the modifier key to space, click on the (currently empty) input box in the right of the third row and press the Space key. It is going to be used as a modifier key for the action.
   [image: rotate]

You can now rotate the view using <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>
You have to unbind *Set 3D Cursor* otherwise the event will not be passed on.

1. You press <kbd>Space</kbd>.
2. You make a <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> down click.
3. *Set 3D Cursor* is called and all other events are aborted.

You can however set *Set 3D Cursor* to a <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> using either **Click** or **Release** as the mouse mode. The action will however only be called once you release the mouse.

Comment: Is it not possible to do this without unbinding LMB?  The idea of using space is that the space bar becomes a modifier key. So when space is pressed, LMB pans, when space is not pressed, LMB does whatever is bound to it without a modifier.

Comment: @Nick Added some info at the end.

Comment: @Nick Yes, it is possible to do this without unbinding LMB. The trick is in placing your "spacebar + LMB" hotkey in a category that "out-prioritizes" the LMB-only hotkeys (specifically: “Screen->Screen Editing”). Full info here: https://blenderartists.org/t/issues-with-spacebar-as-a-modifier-key/570346/4?u=venryx